# perccli: How to check the pdcache status for a virtual drive?

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, dell-perc, lsi

The perccli utility ([doc page](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/poweredge-rc-h330/perc10_plus_hba_clirg/change-virtual-drive-properties-commands?guid=guid-1728a1fb-2866-46a4-93db-ecbdca7de828&lang=en-us)) has an option to set the "pdcache" option, where pdcache means physical drive cache (although I can't find where that's actually defined).  From the docs, the syntax is:

```
perccli /cx/vx set pdcache=On|Off|Default
```

(where /c specified disk controller x or "all" and /vx specified RAID virtual drive x or "all")

My question is, how can I see the current pdcache setting for physical disks?

Background: after much gnashing of teeth, we figured out that when pdcache is on for hard drives with disk local cache (separate from the disk controller cache), and the drive is under high write load, and there's a power failure, then data write commands are lost (as designed).  Note, for enterprise quality SSDs with a tantalum capacitor, the capacitor holds the voltage up long enough for the SSD to flush it's local volatile ram cache to non-volatile flash memory, preventing data corruption.

Thanks in advance
Ben

Comment: `/c0 show all` is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I'm pretty sure perccli is the same as storcli.  These show the PDC is set to default, whatever the mfg (or mfg firmware config) set:

```
storcli /c0 /d0 show
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  90.949 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  90.949 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   0   252:1    3   DRIVE Onln  Y  18.189 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   1   252:0    2   DRIVE Onln  Y  18.189 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   2   252:6    0   DRIVE Onln  Y  18.189 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   3   252:4    1   DRIVE Onln  Y  18.189 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   4   252:5    4   DRIVE Onln  Y  18.189 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   5   252:7    5   DRIVE Onln  Y  18.189 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 - -   -   249:24   15  DRIVE GHS   -  20.008 TB -    -  -   -    -      N  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the `PDC` column: `PDC=PD Cache`

Here is one with PDC forced on:

```
# storcli /c1  /d1 show
Controller = 1
Status = Success
Description = Show Diskgroup Succeeded


TOPOLOGY :
========

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT       Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  140.064 TB enbl N  N   dflt N      N  
 1 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  140.064 TB enbl N  N   dflt N      N  
 1 0   0   249:0    29  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   1   249:1    19  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   2   249:2    30  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   3   249:3    17  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   4   249:4    26  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   5   249:5    6   DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   6   249:6    24  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 1 0   7   249:7    10  DRIVE Onln  Y   20.008 TB enbl N  N   dflt -      N  
 - -   -   249:24   15  DRIVE GHS   -   20.008 TB -    -  -   -    -      N  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

DG=Disk Group Index|Arr=Array Index|Row=Row Index|EID=Enclosure Device ID
DID=Device ID|Type=Drive Type|Onln=Online|Rbld=Rebuild|Dgrd=Degraded
Pdgd=Partially degraded|Offln=Offline|BT=Background Task Active
PDC=PD Cache|PI=Protection Info|SED=Self Encrypting Drive|Frgn=Foreign
DS3=Dimmer Switch 3|dflt=Default|Msng=Missing|FSpace=Free Space Present
TR=Transport Ready
```